# Multiple arrays side-by-side?

Tags: subfloats, arrays

what I've been trying to do is to pack multiple arrays on a single 'row', similar to what subfig module does with images (and tables, I guess); mostly to conserve space.

Something like this:

[image: arrays]

I would use tables and subfig instead of arrays, but I'm not sure how the parentheses would work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just write the array in the same line, without a paragraph break or leaving the math environment, such as

```
\[
  l = \left(\begin{array} ... \end{array}\right) \qquad 
  A = \left(\begin{array} ... \end{array}\right ...
\]
```

resp. matrix environments.

Comment: Darn, why didn't I think of that? This seems like the most straightforward solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
\[
l=\left(\begin{array}{@{}r@{}}
  75.3340\\
  ...
  41.74
  \end{array}\right)
\qquad
A=\left\begin{array}{@{}*5{r}@{}}
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.1772 \\
  ...
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -0.0104
  \end{array}\right)
\]
```

Use the "r" specifier, if you don't want centered entries; the two `@{}` avoid bad spacing on the left and on the right.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
  A=\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\3.14\\5\end{pmatrix} \mkern30mu 
  B=\begin{pmatrix}0.1 & 0.001 & 4\\
                   0.2 & 0.1   & 5\end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]